# How to avoid accidental mutation of a mutable collection?

Tags: scala

So, I wrote a code to compare sorting algorithms. I implemented a few algs as separate classes. Here is a couple for explanation sake.

```
class BubbleSort(input:ListBuffer[Int]){
...
}

class InsertionSort(input:ListBuffer[Int]){
...
}
```

From my driver object, I first create a list, called `input`.
Next, I pass this to new instances of `BubbleSort` and `InsertionSort`.
Then I call a function `sort`, which sorts the ListBuffer I passed during object creation.

```
val input = new ListBuffer[Int]

//Populated input here

val bs = new BubbleSort(input)
val is = new InsertionSort(input)
bs.sort
is.sort
```

The issue I'm facing is, when `is.sort` is called, the list I passed during object creation is already sorted. I guess this is because I called `bs.sort` first, but why does it affect a list in another class?

Any help is appreciated. If you want more code snippets, I'll be glad to share. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
As a temporary fix, instead of creating only one list `input`, I resorted to boilerplate code and created two lists,`bsinput` and `isinput`. Each is then passed to separate classes.

```
val bsinput = new ListBuffer[Int]
val isinput = new ListBuffer[Int]

//Populated both arrays with the same data

val bs = new BubbleSort(bsinput)
val is = new InsertionSort(isinput)
bs.sort
is.sort
```

This solves the problem, but is this the only way? Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

**Edit 2**
As @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez said it was a reference issue. Used `input.clone` and it works now.

Comment: The problem is that you are using a mutable data structure. Thus, as both classes receive the same reference, and as they _(probably)_ sort in place, then after calling `bs.sort`, `input` will be already sorted. You can create a copy of the collection to sort before sorting. Or, even better, just do not mutate _(at lest not the input)_ and return a new sorted collection instead.

Comment: You are right. They do sort in place. So the issue was that scala sent the reference instead of a copy. Instead of passing `input`, I passed `input.clone`. Worked like a charm

Comment: Just for clarification, **Scala** will never pass a _copy_, it will pass the _reference_, just like **Java**. On **Scala**, we usually do not worry about that, since we prefer immutability. As such, sharing references is never a problem, and for collections makes more sense than copying the entire collection for each call.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well if I pass `input` as a `List`, then I'd have to copy it inside `BubbleSort`( and of course `InsertionSort`) into a a `ListBuffer`. So at the end of the day the number of copies created is the same. So of the two which is the more _scala_ way?

Comment: Well, most people will argue that mutating the input is _"bad"_ _(as you can see, this can cause unexpected bugs)_, thus I would suggest avoid that. Both algorithms can be written in a **functional** way using only recursion. However, **Scala** is not a pure functional language, and one of its capabilities _(IMHO the best one)_ is that it allows you to use the style which you consider the best. Thus, other option would be to either use a mutable collection or a immutable collection with a `var` _(the latter is more safe)_ on the local scope of your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing twice a reference to the same mutable collection `ListBuffer`. 
It means both of your sorting algorithms will be working on the same collection and therefore on the second time, your list buffer will be already sorted.

To avoid accidental mutations you just need to create a defensive copy each time you pass it:

```
val input1 = new ListBuffer[Int]

//Populated input here

val input2 = input1.clone

val bs = new BubbleSort(input1)
val is = new InsertionSort(input2)
```